# Chosen Multiselect dropdownlist loading issue

Tags: jquery, html, dropdown, jquery-chosen

I am using ‘choosen-select’ for multiselect dropdown list.

I am facing a problem with dropdown list, initially while page loading the list displayed in  enlarge  form(All items are visible and no effect of chosen library)for some moment and then it regain the desired feel and shape of dropdown list.

Please find attached image of before and after page load. 
[Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBeVN.png)

Comment: Add `display: none;` to the multiselect and on document load, make it visible again.

Comment: Remember that for each option in the select element an item is added to the DOM for each one using JQuery. Sounds like the select element is showing before page is ready. Are you using $(document).ready() function before you call .chosen()?

Answer (score 2):

Have you wrapped your script in the `$(document).ready()` function?

**This should ensure that none of your scripts run until the page has been fully loaded.**

Its possible that `.chosen()` is running before your page has even loaded the initial elements first.

More info [here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
  //following code used to generate 2000 items in the select element
  //in order to try and replicate the issue. 
  var counter = 2000;
  for( var i=1; i <= counter; i++ )
  {
    $(".chosen-select").append("<option> item " + i + "</option>");
  }

  //Initialise JQuery chosen library on select element 
  $(".chosen-select").chosen();
});
```

```html
<!-- Links to external resources and JQuery 2.1.1 !-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.min.css">

<!-- HTML !-->
<select multiple class="chosen-select"></select>
```

---

Also, make sure that you are referencing the *JQuery* library **before** you reference the *chosen* library in your markup.

Comment: how can i  multiselect in this example?

Comment: @CaiqueRomero Try again

Comment: Good! I exclude my answer and I upvoted for yours. Recognizing it more appropriate.

Comment: @MasterYoda Thanks for quick response. My script in $(document).ready(). I am using mvc and my dropdown list is strongly typed thats my dropdown list is bind before document.ready call.

Comment: @daredevil Roughly how many results are returned in your select datasource? remember that for each result returned chosen must create an entry in the DOM. This is probably where the delay is happening when instantiating Chosen. You can test this reducing your dataset, if it loads quicker, thats your problem. Also please add the order in which you include your scripts, JQuery should load first then chosen. However loading chosen after a bunch of other scripts can cause this issue too. Im assuming you are using bundles as you use MVC?

Answer (score 0):

You may hide it until the page is loaded?

**CSS**

```
#your-dropdown{
    display:none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(window).load(function() {
  // When the page has loaded
  $("#your_dropdown").fadeIn(1000);
});
```